# Why datastore Query on parent kind fails?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I understand datastore works like a file system but it seems it doesn't behave   like a file system.
Given the parent kind "parent" and child(current) kind "child" a query on "parent" kind alone(not the complete key) fails to return any result. Why is that if it's like a file system?

I see the hierarchy like this:  `/parent/parentKeyID/child/childKeyID`. Is it wrong?

Comment: The data store doesn't work a like a filesystem.  Parents don't have to exist for instance.  In addition each part of the ekement  of path is made up of a (type and key/id)  So the path key in your example implies you have an entity type "parent" with an id of "parektnKey" and another entitiy type "child" with an id of "childKey" and the full key is ((parent, parentKey),(child, childKey)) +  a possible namespace, and a appid.

Comment: @TimHoffman what I find intriguing  is that I can query over the parent key `/parent/parentKeyID`. How/why is that possible but is not possible to query over the parent kind alone?

Comment: Because a parent key is a complete key.  There is no index of partial keys.

Comment: FYI you still can use prefix queries using inequality filters `>=`, `<` but without using ancestors.